# Can I work with Many Fact Tables? My DW has many fact tables, to diferent products

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, star-schema

Can I work with many fact tables? In my model I have many fact tables cause I have multiple diferent products in my company.

But the model in analysis services became big, today we have 60 tables in analysis services model.

Is there any documentation about this theme? In all kimbal documentation I only read thins about one Big fact table.

But im Afraid that i could follow the wrong strategy and have problems in the future.

Comment: Each Fact table should have a specific purpose (specific measure) and it should be defined using the finest grain.  You have have multiple facts table in your DW but again ideally they should be independent.

Answer (score 0):

Fact tables do not have a complex mechanism but if you keep adding fact tables in your analysis reports, these can manipulate and complicate your analysis and even can create performance issues related to data fetching from DWH Cubes. Pleas read below topic for detailed information about the facts and decide for yourself as per your business requirement:

https://www.nuwavesolutions.com/fact-tables/